# problem with create database if not exist via postgres backup and restore tool

Tags: postgresql, psql, restore, pg-dump, pg-restore

I wrote a bat script for executing the Postgres backup and restore tool.

I have a little issue with the restore flow:
Its works fine as long as my database exists. But if it doesn't it will fail.
**My restore command:**

> "pg_restore.exe"  -d postgres://postgres:1234@127.0.0.1:9195/mydb -w
> -c -v -F c --if-exists "DatabaseBackup_mydb.tar" 2>> "DatabaseRestore_mydb.log"

So I need to modify that command somehow that will handle also a use case in which the database "mydb" doesn't exist, and create it in such a case.

just adding the -C flag won't work in that case.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Should work by using `postgres://postgres:1234@127.0.0.1:9195/postgres` and adding `-C`. Obviously test on throw away instance.  This will connect to `postgres` database `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;` , then `CREATE DATABASE mydb`, connect to `mydb` and then restore the database objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work by using `postgres://postgres:1234@127.0.0.1:9195/postgres` and adding `-C`. Obviously test on throw away instance. This will connect to postgres database `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;` , then `CREATE DATABASE mydb`, connect to `mydb` and then restore the database objects.

To demonstrate:

```
\l test_db
                       List of databases
 Name | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges 
------+-------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------
(0 rows)

pg_restore -d postgres -c -C -U postgres test_db.out 
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 4734; 1262 1170111 DATABASE test_db postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  database "test_db" does not exist
Command was: DROP DATABASE test_db;
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 1

 \l test_db
                               List of databases
  Name   |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
---------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 test_db | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(1 row)

pg_restore -d postgres -c -C -U postgres test_db.out

\l test_db
                               List of databases
  Name   |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
---------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 test_db | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: You should add your comment above to the answer. As it is, it lacks explanations.

Comment: Indeed its works. Thanks!